# Azure Data Factory Source Dataset Connection Fails

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to use Azure Data Factory to move data from MySQL to On-premises SQL database. I need to import data from Destnation SQL database into dataset. I am able to connect to the SQL database when I create a dataset, but why can't I connect to the database while using the dataset in source settings? I tried different solutions, but no luck.

I can successfully connect to Destination Database while creating Linked Service & Dataset.

[image]

But when I want to use this dataset to load the data, it gives me connection error.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what could be wrong here? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your MySQL, on Azure? Azure you sure you can connect to On-premises SQL database in data flow?

Comment: SQL server is on virtual machine. I can connect to database at the time of creating the Dataset but when I try to use the dataset in Data-flow it gives connection error.

Comment: did you connect to the SQL Sever on VM with private endpoint?

Comment: No, I'm using public endpoint. The same connection works for other steps in dataflow- i.e. I am reading last inserted datetime from database and updating it again- this works.  But when I try to use dataset in dataflow- that fails.